# Sharepoint count if

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation

If I created List1, is there any possible ways to have some counting like List2?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: you mean anyone who creates another list, then its name should be List2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Workflows you can use Create List Item and Update List Item actions so that whenever a user adds a value for Blue the amount will be added in another list's column which contains the previous amounts already.

Comment: I have thought about it before but when user update the record from "Red" to "Blue" is seems impossible to -1 for Red and +1 for Blue. Im thinking about is there anyway for user to manually press start workflow and the workflow will read through all items in List1 and then update List2?